# Can I see implementation of UDF function in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, security, apache-spark-sql

As I discovered Spark SQL does not have hashing functions. In order to select specific hashed data I need to use custom/UDF function like this

```
    sparkSession.udf.register("hashFuncWithSecret", (s: String) => myHashFunction(s, "my_very_secret_key"))
```

I want "my_very_secret_key" not be exposed and visible from other spark session or elsewhere in UI or other. I wonder if this is possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not be visible from other Spark session. Farthest you can get is:

```
scala> spark.catalog.listFunctions.show(false)
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|name |database|description|className                                            |isTemporary|
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|!    |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Not        |true       |
|%    |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Remainder  |true       |
|&    |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BitwiseAnd |true       |
|*    |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Multiply   |true       |
|+    |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Add        |true       |
|-    |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Subtract   |true       |
...
```

This is not going to display the definition though.